# I have an issue regarding directories in php and how to string them

Tags: php, html

So I am writing a website and a feature of such website is to allow the user to upload pictures of a specific character. I have written some php code in order to get a value from a form and then decide the directory it shall put the images in.

i am running XAMPP with Apache 2 and when the code is run the file that was inputted previously is not being put into the target folder. And an alert message "file was not uploaded" is being displayed which is hardcoded.

```
if($Character == "Bangalore"){
  $target_dir = "/Characters/Bangalore/";
}
elseif($Character == "Blooudhound"){
  $target_dir = "/Characters/Blooudhound/";
}
elseif($Character == "Caustic"){
  $target_dir = "/Characters/Caustic/";
}

//(etc...)

elseif($Character == "Wraith"){
  $target_dir = "/Characters/Wraith/";
}
else{
  $target_dir = "/uploads/";  
}
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//(etc...)

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

//Report if this was moved or not
```

This is the php code

```
<select name="Character">
  <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="Bloodhound">Bloodhound</option>
  <option value="Caustic">Caustic</option>
  <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
  <option value="Lifeline">Lifeline</option>
  <option value="Mirage">Mirage</option>
  <option value="Octane">Octane</option>
  <option value="Pathfinder">Pathfinder</option>
  <option value="Wraith">Wraith</option>
</select>
```

This is the html code.

Comment: _...php is confusing me_, is not a very clear problem description. Could you try to show us what isn't working as expected, any error messages?

Comment: The file isn't moving that's the only error.

Comment: It could be helpful if you share your file/folder directory structure.

Comment: The file Directory is as follows: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\UberDuber\Characters
In characters there are all the characters as can be seen in the html code with the same capitalization. This code hasn't worked for all of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory format has to be as follows: 
`$target_dir = "Characters/Wraith/";`
not
  $target_dir = "/Characters/Wraith/";